# WPF BindingListCollectionView to ListCollectionView for DataTable as ItemsSource

Tags: datatable, itemssource, listcollectionview

I want to do custom sorting on a ListView which has a DataTable as ItemsSource:

```
myListView.ItemsSource = (data as DataTable);
```

And this are the first lines of my sorting function:

```
DataView view = (myListView.ItemsSource as DataTable).DefaultView;

ListCollectionView coll = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(view);
```

The second line throws an execption like:

Unable to cast "System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView" to "System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView"

Has anyone a solution? Thx 4 answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns an ICollectionView that is not a ListCollectionView.  You most likely want a view on top of a view to get the features that ListCollectionView has.  And since ICollectionView implements CollectionChanged, you wouldn't want to use BindingListCollectionView.

```
DataView view = (myListView.ItemsSource as DataTable).DefaultView;

ListCollectionView coll = new ListCollectionView(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(view));
```

Although an alternative would be:

```
DataView view = (myListView.ItemsSource as DataTable).DefaultView;

BindingListCollectionView coll = new BindingListCollectionView(view);
```

If you only wanted only one view.

If you are binding directly to a WPF control, it is best to bind directly to it without making a BindingListCollectionView/ListCollectionView, as DefaultView already allows sorting of the DataTable.

```
Binding binding = new Binding() { Source = (myListView.ItemsSource as DataTable) };

this.myListView.SetBinding(myListView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);

DataView view = (myListView.ItemsSource as DataTable).DefaultView;

view.Sort = "Age";
```

Hopefully Helpful,

TamusJRoyce