# Custom Sorting Algorithm to BindingListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I am working on a WPF project which has some `DataGrid`'s, and in some of them I need to apply a custom sorting algorithm. So I have been searching a way to accomplish this and in many web pages I have found the following code:

```
var myListView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myDataGrid.ItemsSource);

ListCollectionView myListCollectionView = myListView as ListCollectionView;

myListCollectionView.CustomSort = new CustomSorter();

.
.
.

public class CustomSorter : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        // sorting logic ...
    }
}
```

That seems to be a very good method to carry out a custom sort, but my problem is that I cannot cast my variable `myListView` to `ListCollectionView` because it turned out to be a `BindingListCollectionView` object which besides lacks of functionality to set a custom sorting algorithm.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890371/wpf-bindinglistcollectionview-to-listcollectionview-for-datatable-as-itemssource) solution but it does not work for me because they try to do the following:

```
ListCollectionView coll = new ListCollectionView(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myDataGrid.ItemsSource));
```

But there is no constructor that takes as a paremeter a ICollectionView object (which is what function GetDefaultView returns).

**So, is there any way to apply a custom sorting algorithm to a BindingListCollectionView object?**

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately, the solution has be placed in a `DataGrid` devided class, since the solution has to be generic.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Make your property `MyPropertyToSortOn` of a custom type that implements IComparable, then add a sort descriptor to your listview:

```
ListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("MyPropertyToSortOn", ListSortDirection.Descending))


public class MyPropertyClass: IComparable{
  public int CompareTo(object obj) {
    //custom comparison implemented here, returns -1,0 or 1
  }
}
```

...

```
public class MyDataClass{
   public MyPropertyClass MyPropertyToSortOn {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, do I have to implement that property in the type my items are made of?

Comment: Yes, thank you, but actually I was wordering if there is a way to make the sort but in a DataGrid derived class since I cannot modify my "DataClass" because it is a `DataSet` generated by the XSD tool, and I dont belong to the team responsible for doing that.

Comment: @Dante if the data class comes from elsewhere you can always inherit from it and implement the comparison there